# In Python, read in csv file with columns of data and assign variables according to the column headers

Tags: python, csv

I am dealing with CSV files that are similar to the following ('testcsv.csv'):

```
x, y, z
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
```

That is, the first column contains headers with the names of variables, and the subsequent columns contain numerical values representing arrays corresponding to these variables. I would like to read the variables into my 'workspace' (to use a Matlab term) such that "x" is the array [1,4], "y" is the array [2,5], and "z" is the array [3,6]. The following script achieves this:

```
import numpy as np

filename='testcsv.csv'
# Read column headers (to be variable naames)
with open(filename) as f:
     firstline = f.readline()                    # Read first line of csv
     firstline = firstline.replace("\n","")      # Remove new line characters
     firstline = firstline.replace(" ","")       # Remove spaces
     ColumnHeaders = firstline.split(",")        # Get array of column headers

# Read in the data (omitting the first row containing column headers)
data=np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=1,delimiter=",")

# Assign the data to arrays, with names of the variables generated from column headers
Ind=0
for Var in ColumnHeaders:
    vars()[Var]=data[:,Ind]         # Assign the columns of the data to variables names after the column headers
    Ind=Ind+1
```

The only problem is that I would like to make this a function, which takes "filename" as input and writes out the variables globally. I'm aware of the "global" function, but I'm not quite sure how to use it since the variable names are obtained dynamically. Any ideas?

Comment: How about something like `x, y, z = some_function(filename)`? Much cleaner than fiddling with `globals`.

Comment: _"I'm not quite sure how to use it since the variable names are obtained dynamically"_. Wouldn't it be exactly the same, except you use `globals()` instead of `vars()`?

Comment: I would recommend `pandas` to get a nice column-named interface for csv-type files, no need to re-invent the functionality.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your simple solution. For reference I've incorporated it in my own answer below.

Comment: I would **highly** recommend you try out the `csv` module - it'll handle all this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Kevin's advice, I simply replaced "vars()" by "globals()". Here is the new script:

```
import numpy as np

filename='testcsv.csv'

def read_csv(filename):

# Read column headers (to be variable naames)
with open(filename) as f:
     firstline = f.readline()                    # Read first line of csv
     firstline = firstline.replace("\n","")      # Remove new line characters
     firstline = firstline.replace(" ","")       # Remove spaces
     ColumnHeaders = firstline.split(",")        # Get array of column headers

# Read in the data (omitting the first row containing column headers)
data=np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=1,delimiter=",")

# Assign the data to arrays, with names of the variables generated from column headers
Ind=0
for Var in ColumnHeaders:
    globals()[Var]=data[:,Ind]         # Assign the columns of the data to variables names after the column headers
    Ind=Ind+1

read_csv(filename)
```

(The lines within the "def" should be indented too but this copy-pasting didn't capture this). The script now uses a function "read_csv" as desired.